# How Angular2 components can be fit in the same page?

Tags: css, html, angular, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

i'm trying to fit couple of components to make each of them to take a full page
i want the first component to fit all the screen (like a landing page)
and to have the browser scroll bar so i can scroll down to see the second component. (i would like to add hover arrow to let the user know he can scroll down)
but when i try to fit them together its showing me them on the same page.
any suggestions?
im using Boostrap4 and flexbox 
thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried already

Comment: i have 2 components, <app-component1></app-component1>  and <app-component2> </app-compoentn2> i want the first component to take the full width  and height of the screen, and when i scroll down to see the second component fit the all screen width and height. that's it. when i try this i see them both in the same page.  if its not clear yet ill add the code. thanks. @Juxture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if i understand correctly this should do what you want. I made a simple fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o1uwahL8/

HTML:

```
<div id="componentOne">
  Component 1

  <div>
     <a href="#componentTwo">Go to two</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="componentTwo">
  Component 2
</div>
```

I used divs here, but this should not be different from your component selectors.

CSS:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#componentOne {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#componentTwo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Be sure all the wrapping tags have their height set to 100% or this will not work!

If you have any further questions, ask away.

P.S if you want a smooth scroll to the second component you can use something like this: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)